# String Array dimension set considering user input

Tags: java, arrays, loops, input, java.util.scanner

I wrote some code. The idea is to ask user how many names they wish to enter, get the input and set the string array size accordingly.
I have managed to finalise the code apart from setting array size.
When I try something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many names do you wish to enter?");
        int numOfNames = read.nextInt();

        String [] names = new String[numOfNames];
```

I get an error saying String cannot be converted to int.
I tried stuff I found online like trying and converting int to string etc but didn't work.
My source code is here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayDemoS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("How many names do you wish to enter?");
       int numOfNames = read.nextInt();

       String [] names = new String[6];

       System.out.println("Enter the names.");
       int items = 0;

       do {
           names[items] = read.nextLine();
       } while ( ++items <= numOfNames);

       System.out.println("You entered the following names");

       for ( int i = 0; i <= numOfNames; i++) {
          System.out.print(names[i] + " ");
       }

       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I set the size to 6 assuming the user will enter 5 names.
There might be other ways of doing this using ArrayList etc but I haven't learned about them yet. I am able to do the same task when the array is formed of int type data. I would like to be able to do it for String type as well. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: give your input sample and complete error details

Comment: Your complete code example does not throw any errors. Please provide a code example together with complete error message (including reported line number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("How many names do you wish to enter?");
   int numOfNames = read.nextInt();

   String [] names = new String[numOfNames];

   System.out.println("Enter the names.");
   int items = 0;
   names[items] = read.nextLine();
   while ( items < numOfNames)
   {
       names[items] = read.nextLine();
       items++;
   }

   System.out.println("You entered the following names");

   for ( int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++) {
      System.out.print(names[i] + " ");
   }

   System.out.println();
}
```